# Is there a package to secure rendered pdf with a password?

Tags: packages, drm

Is there a package and command that can secure rendered pdf with a password?

Comment: You mean to encrypt it with a password? See [Is it possible to produce a PDF with un-copyable text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text) and [Protect text in PDF from being copied](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18542/protect-text-in-pdf-from-being-copied/18547#18547). I thought there is an exact duplicate for this but I can't find it. Anyway, PDF encryption support got dropped from `pdftex` a while ago and I don't think `xetex` has it as well. You need to use an external tool on the compiled PDF afterwards to add this.

Comment: This is not really a TeX question, maybe superuser would be a better place for it.

Comment: Un-copyable text sounds like a good idea also but not necessary. Basically, when you open the PDF file, it should present you with a password dialog. If you pass, you can open the PDF, otherwise you can't read it.

Comment: @Level1Coder: See my updated comment above. I don't think any TeX supports this. You need to use external tools like `pdftk` or Adobe Acrobat (full version, not just the Reader).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There used to be a package achieving PDF encryption, but it relied on obsolete pdfTeX patches: [`pdfcrypt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrypt)

Nowadays, you need an external tool to encrypt your PDF. Here is an example to encrypt a PDF with [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/):

```
pdftk inputfile.pdf output outputfile.pdf encrypt_128bit owner_pw yourownerpw user_pw youruserpw
```

That said, I guess a LaTeX package could be done to make use of `pdftk` at compile time.

Just please remember that no PDF encryption is really bullet-proof. Once the user can *see* the PDF, then he can *print* it and *edit* it. It can just require the use of other tools than the Adobe thingies.

Comment: Note that it is really recommended to use 128bit encryption (as shown here). The "normal" 40bit encryption is do to US export restrictions and is not very safe (3 days of computation power of a normal PC, I heard a ca. 8 years ago, should be done to .5 day by now).

Comment: Yes, although in some countries it is illegal to use high-level encryption altogether. Here in France, I believe you have to give a copy of the private key to the police when you do so (although when you go to the police with your fingerprint, they think you're totally crazy to tell the truth ;-))

Comment: It looks like you need the commercial version for $3,99 to add a password?

Comment: @doncherry: Just tested it with Debian's `pdftk` package. It works great. I'm guessing you need the Pro version if you want to use the GUI for that maybe.

Answer (score 22):

In the case of pdfTeX, an external tool, such as `pdftk` or `qpdf`, is necessary to encrypt.
In the case of XeTeX, we can use a `\special` supported by `xdvipdfmx`,
for example:

```
\special{pdf:encrypt ownerpw (abc) userpw (xyz) length 128 perm 2052}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome, solved my problem in the easiest way. (was using ShareLatex.com which has a XeLaTeX engine)

Comment: Can you explain the used options, in particular the `perm` setting?

Comment: @bonanza: You may find useful data in `texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for lualatex?

Comment: @bonanza: I don't know. Probably there is not.

Comment: Can anyone explain, how to use this with TeXMaker?