# Xelatex engine encryption pdf problem: dvipdfmx whether there are bugs?

Tags: xetex, dvipdfmx, drm

I use the method mentioned here ["Is there a package to secure rendered pdf with a password?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/is-there-a-package-to-secure-rendered-pdf-with-a-password/237093#237093).

```
\special{pdf:encrypt ownerpw (abc) userpw (xyz) length 128 perm 2052}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Tested:

1. Win7 64bit + MiKTeX 2.9 32bit

   **Did not use the owner password "abc"  to encrypt the pdf, but the user password "xyz" by setting.**

   miktex-dvipdfmx.exe Version:

   ```
   This is xdvipdfmx Version 20160619 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
   modified for TeX Live and MiKTeX,
   an extended version of DVIPDFMx, which in turn was
   an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

   Copyright (C) 2002-2016 the DVIPDFMx project team
   Copyright (C) 2006-2016 SIL International.

   This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   ```
2. macOS 10.12 + MacTeX-2016

   The problem is the same as above.

   dvipdfmx Version:

   ```
   This is dvipdfmx Version 20160307 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
   modified for TeX Live,
   an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

   Copyright (C) 2002-2016 the DVIPDFMx project team
   Copyright (C) 2006-2016 SIL International.

   This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   ```
3. There is no problem with the [cloud.sagemath.com](https://cloud.sagemath.com) platform.

   Compile command:

   ```
   latexmk -xelatex -f -g -bibtex -synctex=1 --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode 'text.tex'
   ```

   dvipdfmx Version:

   ```
   This is dvipdfmx Version 20150315 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
   modified for TeX Live,
   an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

   Copyright (C) 2002-2015 the DVIPDFMx project team
   Copyright (C) 2006 SIL International.

   This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   ```
4. There is no such problem with the [www.sharelatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com)  platform.

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been introduced in the option

```
-S
```

from some day.
Workaround: when you use

```
\special{pdf:encrypt ...}
```

command-line options

```
-S, -P, -K
```

are not necessary. If you remove these options, you will succeed.
The bug in the option

```
-S
```

was fixed in the TeX Live SVN.
Anyway, it is simpler not to use command-line
options for encryption when you use the special:

```
\special{pdf:encrypt ...}
```