# Create alternative uppercase text automatically with accsupp

Tags: pdf, small-caps, copy-paste, accsupp

This is a follow-up question to [Is it possible to provide alternative text to use when copying text from the PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf).

I am essentially trying to redefine `textsc`/`scshape` in order to use `accsupp` automatically, i.e. that the copied text is in uppercase automatically. I've been playing around with the `textcase` package, but without success:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\RequirePackage{textcase}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\newsc}[1]{
    {\scshape{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=#1}%
    \MakeTextLowercase{#1}%
    \EndAccSupp{}}%
    }}

\newsc{This could be} the beginning of a chapter

But there is a \newsc{mysterious} whitespace

\end{document}
```

What I would want is to wrap `ActualText=#1` into something like `ActualText=\MakeTextUppercase{#1}`, but that does not work as I get a `Generic error: undefined control sequence`.

There are a few more issues:

- there is a whitespace before text wrapped in the `\newsc` command
- I am unsure how to redefine the small caps commands to incorporate the new feature (hence I created a new command in the MWE)
- In the quoted answer Ulrike mentions something like `\expandafter\PDFreplace\expandafter{\USA}` to make the text selectable for each character. How would that work with my example?

**Edit**: I just realised that this approach breaks completely when trying to use accsupp in headings in conjunction with hyperref. The error is:

```
! Extra \else.
\KV@split ...errx {\@tempa \space undefined}\else 
                                                  \ifx \@empty #3\@empty \KV...
l.27 ...This could be} the beginning of a chapter}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a trailing space right after your definition. Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{textcase}
\newcommand\newsc[1]{%
    {\scshape%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=#1}%
    \MakeTextLowercase{#1}%
    \EndAccSupp{}}}
\let\textsc\newsc

\begin{document}    
\newsc{This could be} the beginning of a chapter

But there is a \textsc{Mysterious} whitespace

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jörg: two solved ;-)

Comment: I do not undestand your \USA problem.

Comment: Thats the smallest issue. When you use accsupp like in your MWE you can only select the full word, and not each character. @josefec apparently solved that with a hint from Ulrike, but I don't understand the solution from the comments.

Comment: I see: you have to define the command in that way and then if `\def\USA{usa}` you have to use `\expandafter\textsc\expandafter{\USA}`

Comment: I just realised that this approach breaks completely when trying to use accsupp in headings in conjunction with hyperref...