# How to fix missing or incorrect mappings from glyphtounicode.tex

Tags: symbols, pdftex, unicode, characters, copy-paste

`glyphtounicode.tex` has been described as the best solution for generating copy-and-pasteable symbols. However, I find that various symbols that I need to use do not paste as the appropriate Unicode codepoints/characters. **How can I fix this?**

This is how my macros *should* be pasting:

- `\nSubset`: ⋐̸ (U+22D0 U+0338)
- `\cong`: ≅ (U+2245)
- `\ncong`: ≇ (U+2247)
- `\bigcup`: ⋃ (U+22C3)
- `\notin`: ∉ (U+2209)
- `\neq`: ≠ (U+2260)
- `\llbracket`: ⟦ (U+27E6); `\rrbracket`: ⟧ (U+27E7)
- `\llparenthesis`: (|; `\rrparenthesis`: |)

  - **Update:** Unicode offers the symbol pairs ⦇ ⦈ (U+2987/U+2988) and ⦅ ⦆ (U+2985/U+2986), which many might consider a better choice for these macros.
- `\coloneqq`: ≔ (U+2254)
- `\models`: ⊧ (U+22A7) [currently |=]
- `\Rsh`: ↱ (U+21B1)
- `\textlengthmark`: ː (U+02D0) [currently :]
- `\blackdiamond`: ⬩ (U+2B29)
- `\sqbullet`: ▪ (U+25AA)
- `\square`: ▫ (U+25AB)

*(Note: Earlier I erroneously stated that `\neg` pastes incorrectly as ￢ (U+FFE2) instead of ¬ (U+00AC). This is not correct: `\neg` pastes correctly; it's Word that replaces this by the other symbol, just as I noticed that Word doesn't copy all accented letters correctly from pdf-files (whereas they paste exactly right into Notepad). I actually don't know whether this is truly a Word issue (if so, it's likely a legacy encoding/font hack) or has to do with `pdflatex` or maybe the Unicode/non-Unicode clipboard distinction in Windows. Anyone feel free to add (non-ranty) insight into this.)*

This is how they currently paste:

```
>; ; ;
S
; <; ,; J; K; L; M;B; |=;é; :; ˛; ‚; ˝
```

(The linebreaks before and after `\bigcup` ("S") are probably caused by it being a big operator, so they're nothing to worry about.)

Here is minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode % I am using the updated version from http://www.lcdf.org/type/ (lcdf-typetools-2.94.tar.gz).
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc} % The T3-encoding is required by the tipa-package.
\usepackage[noenc,safe]{tipa} % \textlengthmark
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket,llparenthesis,rrparenthesis]{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[mathb]{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\noindent \( \nSubset; \cong; \ncong; \bigcup; \notin; \neq; \llbracket; \rrbracket; \llparenthesis; \rrparenthesis; \coloneqq; \models; \Rsh; \mbox{\textlengthmark}; \blackdiamond; \sqbullet; \square\) \\

\noindent \( \nexists \)

\end{document}
```

The symbol ∄ (`\nexists`) at the end has been included to demonstrate that `glyphtounicode.tex` is compatible with my code, because it pastes correctly (and in fact requires a *recent* version of `glyphtounicode.tex`, see the comment in my code).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add your own definitions. Eg. here an example how to copy an "a" as "A":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pdfglyphtounicode{a}{0041} %0041=A
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
aaaaa 
\end{document}
```

The main problem is naturally to find the names of the glyphs you are using. In case you know the font you can find the names in the `afm` or the `pfb`. You can also add `\pdfcompresslevel=0` to your document and then inspect the `pdf`. Look for lines starting with `/CharSet` (there will be more than one if you use more than one font). E.g. if I add `\int` to the example I will find `/CharSet (/integraltext)` and `integraltext` is the name of the glyph.

In case that the symbol is not a single glyph or that its name is not unique or changes from one font family to the next you will probably need to use the `accsupp`-package. [Is it possible to provide alternative text to use when copying text from the PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly why I'm asking: I have *no idea* how to find the names of the glyphs that I am using. I also don't know what it means for a name to not be unique, and all of these involve macros I didn't define myself, so I don't actually know how to obviously and effectively use accsup with this (from superficial inspection). So ideally a solution would give me concrete fixes for the above symbols/macros. Also, some of these do have lines in `glyphtounicode.tex` (`\pdfglyphtounicode{approximatelyequal}{2245}`), so I am not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: @user14996 I added some remarks how to find out the names.

Comment: I appreciate your help and efforts, but I am not sure what difference the `\pdfcompresslevel` would make and what a `pfb` is. I also do not know how to know which font a given macro from a given package is using. Ideally one solution for each case (from someone) and I'll figure out the rest by myself. Sorry ... this is after looking at this for a couple of hours, and I'm a beginner as far as font matters are concerned.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean the `pfb` but the `pdf`. If you add `\pdfcompresslevel=0` to your document and compile then the `pdf` is more or less a normal text file and you can open it in your editor.

Comment: Okay, things make a *lot* more sense now :-) I'll report back when I hit a wall ...

Comment: There is good progress: see my last edit. Is there a straightforward way of redefining the remaining 6 macros to make easy use of the `accsupp` package, or will I need to wrap them into new commandnames? (Immediately wrapping without any mathmode or other caveats should work, right?)

Comment: I would use new command names. I don't know if simply wrapping will work. It could be that you need e.g. `\mathbin` to get the spacing right.

Comment: Done; see above. Do I really need the commands for math character classes? The math character classes I've picked in my above solution are what I think best fit my needs and may not be identical to the symbols' original ones, *but* shouldn't a symbol's math character class remain the same if all I do is wrap it into `accsupp`?

Comment: If you wrap a mathematical symbol e.g. in braces this "hides" its "math meaning" and so can affect spacing. E.g. `$a=b$` has a very different spacing to `$a{=}b$` as in the second case the `=` is not longer a relation.

Answer (score 5):

*The following concrete solution is based on Ulrike Fischer's answer:*

**Solution, part 1 (using `\pdfglyphtounicode`):** The following lines help with the first batch of symbols:

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{notsubsetdbl}{22D0 0338}
\pdfglyphtounicode{simequal}{2245}
\pdfglyphtounicode{notsimequal}{2247}
\pdfglyphtounicode{uniontext}{22C3}
\pdfglyphtounicode{nelement}{2209}
\pdfglyphtounicode{nequal}{2260}
\pdfglyphtounicode{llbracket}{27E6}
\pdfglyphtounicode{rrbracket}{27E7}
\pdfglyphtounicode{llparenthesis}{0028 007C}
\pdfglyphtounicode{rrparenthesis}{007C 0029}
\pdfglyphtounicode{colonequal}{2254}
```

The macros `\models`, `\Rsh`, `\textlengthmark`, `\blackdiamond`, `\sqbullet`, `\square` seem to require the `accsupp` package. In the pdf-file, they are handled with the following glyphnames respectively: bar + equal, eacute, colon, ogonek, quotesinglbase, hungarumlaut. This explains their pasting behavior; these are names with normally different meanings, namely the ones shown by what's being pasted.

**Solution, part 2 (using the package `accsupp`):** The following code creates new "Unicode-compatible" commands. A user will of course need to replace the old commands with these new ones (`\models` by `\Umodels` etc.). The math character classes (`mathord` etc) used here are based on my unique needs.

```
\RequirePackage{accsupp} % Unicode-pastable versions of symbols
  \newcommand*{\Umodels}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=22A7}\mathrel{\models}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\URsh}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=21B1}\mathord{\Rsh}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\Utextlengthmark}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=02D0}\textlengthmark\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\Ublackdiamond}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2B29}\mathord{\blackdiamond}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\Usqbullet}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=25AA}\mathord{\sqbullet}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\Usquare}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=25AB}\mathord{\square}\EndAccSupp{}}
```

(To those who are wondering, the value of `ActualText` can also be a space-separated *list* of hexadecimal UTF-16 values. Note that these are *not* Unicode codepoints but their UTF-16 representation (these are not identical for characters outside of Unicode's basic multilingual plane, BMP). **For more information on how to paste Unicode characters outside of the BMP, see this [question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70712/how-do-i-paste-codepoints-outside-of-the-basic-multilingual-plane-with-accsupp).**)

**Bonus addendum: How to fix existing `\pdfglyphtounicode` assignments:** If you would like to change an existing assignment such as U+25C1 for `\lhd` (`glyphtounicode.tex` contains the line `\pdfglyphtounicode{triangleleft}{25C1}`), simply reinvoke the `\pdfglyphtounicode` macro *after* the line `\input glyphtounicode`; for example you may write `\pdfglyphtounicode{triangleleft}{22B2}`, which will override the original definition.