# How do I paste codepoints outside of the basic multilingual plane with accsupp or \pdfglyphtounicode?

Tags: symbols, pdftex, unicode, copy-paste, accsupp

As described in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66300/how-to-fix-missing-or-incorrect-mappings-from-glyphtounicode-tex), the `accsupp` package can be used to have symbols paste as arbitrary Unicode codepoints. For example you might want to write something like the following, to have blackboard-bold symbols denoting natural numbers, booleans, and strings paste with the Unicode codepoints denoting the corresponding blackboard bold symbols ℕ, ,  (U+2115, U+1D539, U+1D54A) as opposed to just as "N, B, S":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{accsupp}
  \newcommand*{\setNat}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2115}\mathbb{N}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\setBool}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1D539}\mathbb{B}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\setStr}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1D54A}\mathbb{S}\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}
\(\setNat, \setBool, \setStr\)
\end{document}
```

However **the latter two symbols paste incorrectly** as ᵓ, ᵔ (U+1D53 and U+1D54). This problem arises whenever Unicode codepoints larger than hexadecimal U+FFFF are used. **How can one fix this?**

The same issue arises with `\pdfglyphtounicode` lines (with `glyphtounicode.tex`); see the above-linked-to question for examples involving ordinary BMP-characters. So I would also like to ask: How can one fix it there?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Just drawing your attention to this - might be useful to add this to the `accsupp` documentation. (Maybe all this is obvious to an expert already, but it wasn't to me, even though I know Unicode very well.) :-)

Comment: The @-notation does only work, if the user has participated in the thread. I have now have seen the comment by accident because of the recent editing.

Comment: The new version of `accsupp` (currently [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/accsupp-0.4.pdf), installation hints inside until the next release of my bundle) adds a new method `unichar`, where the text can be given as comma separated list of Unicode code point numbers. Numbers outside the BMP are automatically converted to surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `accsupp` package requires "16-bit" Unicode strings. That is for any character outside of the basic multilingual plane (= BMP = plane 0), i.e. a character with a Unicode codepoint larger than hexadecimal U+FFFF, you need to convert its raw Unicode codepoint to its UTF-16 representation. It so happens that for Unicode codepoints of the form U+HHHH any codepoint is identical to its UTF-16 representation. Higher codepoints though need to be converted into so-called *surrogate pair* form to get to their UTF-16 representation. For example, [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) lets you look up such values directly.

The codepoints U+1D539 () and U+1D54A () are D835 DD39 and D835 DD4A (respectively) in UTF-16, so the following code will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{accsupp}
  \newcommand*{\setNat}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2115}\mathbb{N}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\setBool}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=D835 DD39}\mathbb{B}\EndAccSupp{}}
  \newcommand*{\setStr}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=D835 DD4A}\mathbb{S}\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}
\(\setNat, \setBool, \setStr,\)
\end{document}
```

`glyphtounicode.tex`'s `\pdfglyphtounicode` behaves the same: it requires UTF-16. That is, one needs to write `\pdfglyphtounicode{somename}{D835 DD39}` instead of `\pdfglyphtounicode{somename}{1D539}`.

**Note** that of course both `accsupp` (with `method=hex,unicode`) and `\pdfglyphtounicode` accept an arbitrarily long sequence of UTF-16 values.