# How to specify custom symbol encoding

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

I don't know how to properly ask this question nor if the term *encoding* is appropriate for this issue, so I'll start with an example. Say I define a new command `\R` for the set of real numbers as follows

```
\newcommand\R{{\rm I\!R}}
```

so that the output will be something like [image: Custom Reals symbol].

Basically I merge capital letters "I" and "R" to produce something in between a plain-text and a blackboard-bold R. When I select and copy the symbol on the pdf output, the copied text is reasonably the string "IR" rather than just "R".

My question is, **is there any way to define what plain text should be copied** (**and matched** using pdf reader find tool) **in the pdf text selection?** In the example above I would like the output of `\R` to be copied as "R" only, for instance.

More generally, is it possible to define the wanted behavior on arbitrary (more complex) commands? For instance, something like

```
\EncodeAs{plain-text-string}{TeX-command}
```

so that in the example above I could define

```
\newcommand\R{\EncodeAs{R}{{\rm I\!R}}}
```

Comment: The `accsupp` package is what you want.  Here is one of my answers using it to produce different output in PDF visual versus PDF copy/paste: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198516/is-there-such-thing-as-visual-only-whitespace/198519#198519.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\R{{\rm I\!R}}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=R}%
    $\R$%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
\end{document}
`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Why don't you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accsupp` package allows the pdf display text to be set differently from the corresponding PDF copy/paste text.  Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\R{{\rm I\!R}}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=R}%
    $\R$%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
\end{document}
```

The above code will place this

[image]

in the document, while the copy/paste of the PDF will produce an "R".  One can set these in macros, depending on the use case.