# How to increase minimum space between words in XeLaTex output?

Tags: xetex, pdf, copy-paste, output, parsing

**Update:** The problem seems to be that the spacing between some words is too small, and the ATS thinks it's one word. So, the ideal solution would be  to set a minimum spacing across the entire document, rather than manually adding spaces where needed.

I recently uploaded my resume (XeLaTex output) to [Jobscan](http://jobscan.co/), a service that mimics (or purports to mimic) Applicant Tracking Systems (ATS). ATS are used to process incoming resumes before a pair of eyes gets to look at them. This processing involves turning your resume into plain text, and then comparing how many keywords in the job description appear in your resume (and how often), as a way to gauge "surface compatibility," so to speak.

What I noticed though is that many key words in my document weren't counted because Jobscan wasn't parsing whitespace correctly: many ***keywordswere*** mushed together like this, and instead of detecting an instance of each **key** **word**, it detected one instance of 'keywordswere.' The snag is that resumes are sometimes thrown out if they don't hit a key word threshold, so, I worry that it won't even make it to a person if the problem occurs on a real ATS.

I looked around and one option that came up is to use `cmap`, but that doesn't work with XeLaTex, only pdftex. What options could I have, other than going back to a Word document? (pdftex wouldn't work with my current resume template, given my use of fonts).

Comment: See the `accsupp` package.  Ths question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198516/is-there-such-thing-as-visual-only-whitespace, was the exact opposite of yours, in which the PDF output showed spaces, but they wanted the copy/paste of the PDF internals to show no spaces.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I'm reading through the documentation, going to start poking around a bit, but wanted to ask: would you know if it's possible to create a replacement text for the entire document in one go, or would/should I do it section by section?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have never used the package in such an extensive manner to give you a good answer to that question..

Comment: I don't know how your system parse the pdf, but if it does it similar to a normal pdf viewer and its copy&paste and if it only happen sometimes that word space is lost then probably the problem is that the word space is to small here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You were right! Will you submit an answer, maybe with a few links to the different horizontal space options?

Comment: Could you put up an example where the problem arises? Just so we can test what sort of extra space you need in order to avert the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is just enough to slightly increase the minimum word space? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/how-to-shorten-shrink-spaces-between-words

Comment: if you are copying and pasting from a pdf, you should be aware that, unless special steps are taken, (la)tex does *not* insert space *characters* between words, only "glue", which is equivalent to a position shirt.  without a space *character*, ordinary copy-and-paste techniques will not recognize the gap as a reproducible space character.  (i went through this last year when a latex document i wrote was converted to word for publication, using copy-and-paste from a pdf file rather than from the tex source, which would have been *much* more reliable.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fontspec has an option WordSpace that you can use to increase the word space. Be aware that is a global option of a font. If you want to use the same font with a different word space you must e.g. scale it a bit:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}[WordSpace={2.5,1.2,0}]

\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=1.01]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\sffamily

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the syntax for the WordSpace option (from the documentation):

"For those times when the precise details are important, the WordSpace feature is provided, which takes either a single scaling factor to scale the default value, or a triplet of comma-separated values to scale the nominal value, the stretch, and the shrink of the interword space by, respectively. (WordSpace={x} is the same as WordSpace={x,x,x}.)"

Comment: This looks very promising, though could you explain the options inside the bracket? [Wordspace = {...}]. Also props for the scaling tip!

Comment: Well fontspec has a documentation. Why don't you look up the syntax there?

Comment: I did. Just thought it would be a more complete answer.

Comment: Syntax explanation, for posterity: 
"The space in between words in a paragraph will be chosen automatically, and generally will not need to be adjusted. For those times when the precise details are important,
the WordSpace feature is provided, which takes either a single scaling factor to scale the default value, or a triplet of comma-separated values to scale the nominal value, the stretch,
and the shrink of the interword space by, respectively. (WordSpace={x} is the same as WordSpace={x,x,x}.)"

Comment: Just finished testing, making sure it worked well. Thanks again!