# l e t t e r s p a c i n g with soul/soulutf8

Tags: pdf, soul, letterspacing, soulutf

I use  l e t t e r s p a c i n g  provided by `soul`/`soulutf8` to emphasize words.
But

- If I try to copy a spaced word from the pdf-file, then I get "w o r d" instead of "word".
- Also the search for "word" in pdf-file does not return the spaced word.

> Is there a trick to fix this problem?

Comment: with soul imho the only thing that could work is to add an /ActualText with accsupp. With lualatex,  microtype and fontspec it can work out of the box if the pdf is tagged and real space chars are used, but not in all pdf viewers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I am staring at https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/axessibility/axessibility.pdf but it does not help so far. Could you give me a more precise hint?

Comment: No that won't work. The only one that works is tagpdf. But see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605142/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry, still could you say what has to be written instead of `\so{word}`?

Comment: Search this site for uses of `accsupp`, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use/233397#233397 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198516/is-there-such-thing-as-visual-only-whitespace

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you very much, I will use it to answer my question, so it will be removed from unanswered.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: To mark the question as solved, you may mark the answer as accepted (green checkmark), including your own answer. Also, please see my suggestion concerning the `letterspace` package.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved, thanks to [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233397/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\newcommand\an[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#1}}}%
      \so{#1}%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\def\emph{\an}

\begin{document}
Try to copy this \emph{word} --- you will see ``word'', but not ``\emph{word}''. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already found a satisfactory solution by (1) using `accsupp` and also (2) reducing the tracking (=*intraword* spacing) from a whopping 0.25em (`\textso`'s default) to 0.1em. (In my experience, no. (2) by itself can solve the search and copy issue with most PDF readers.)

In addition, I would like to suggest abandoning `soul(utf8)` in favor of the superior letterspacing tool from [pkg `microtype`](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) (available separately as pkg `letterspace`). Particularly if you have to deal with long portions of text, indexing commands, or the like.

`soulutf8`, despite the recent updates and the Unicode compatibility, still suffers from some limitations of the old `soul` package. `\textso` interacts poorly with some other macros. Of the more common ones, using `\index` or `\cite` in the argument aborts compilation, while using `\mbox` or math mode breaks the letterspacing functionality (examples below). There are workarounds, but they can get pretty ugly: in the last example, you'd need to "close" and "reopen" `\textso` every time, which in turn makes for too short *inter*word spaces.

`letterspace` handles these cases easily, besides being more flexible in choosing the amount of letterspacing (case by case or globally). And of course, it can be combined with `accsupp` as in Steven Segletes' and your approach.

[image: letterspacing examples]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letterspace}                % or microtype
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}

\textso{triangle $ABC$} (\verb|\textlso|)   

\textls[250]{triangle $ABC$} (\verb|\textls|)

\bigskip

\textls{foo \mbox{bar} \index{baz}baz (\cite{mybook})} 
(\verb|\textls|, mbox index and cite succeed)

\textls[250]{foo bar baz} (\verb|\textls|)

%\textso{foo bar \index{baz}baz} (\verb|\textlso|)          % doesn't compile!
%\textso{foo bar baz \cite{mybook}} (\verb|\textlso|)       % doesn't compile!

\textso{foo \mbox{bar} \protect\index{baz}baz (\protect\cite{mybook})} 
(\verb|\textlso|, mbox index and cite prevent letterspacing)

\textso{foo} \mbox{\textso{bar}} \index{baz}\textso{baz} (\cite{mybook}) 
(\verb|\textlso|, requires some contorsions, messes up interword spaces)

\end{document}
```