# Solve search for rotated or tilted words within the Zathura PDF viewer

Tags: viewers

I do not know how far this topic belongs to the field of TeX's languages and their derivatives, but I leave my question below.

\

I want to know why Zathura does not find words that are rotated or tilted, and whether there is any solution to that.

[Zathura project](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura)

Comment: You might be able to provide the original text with the `accsupp` package, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf.

Comment: Following their recommendations really worked, grateful @Marijn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommendations of @Marijn, I present the solution in a MWE:

[image: Print of the search with Zathura]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){Text};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {Text};
\draw [circle connection bar]
    (energy1) edge (energy2)
    ;
    \draw (energy1)--node[orange, sloped,above=0.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm]{\textsc{%
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=USA}%
  usa%
 \EndAccSupp{}}%
}(energy2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```