# For an arbitrary TeX-internal entity (e.g. METAPOST, TIPA), associate a unicode value for PDF copy/paste

Tags: unicode, tipa

Latin Modern Roman has bad output for certain unicode combinations, including ā́ (small Latin 'a' with macron and acute accent). This can be remedied by using the [TIPA package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) for these combinations, thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  native Latin Modern Roman `a with acute stacked on top of macron': & ā́\\
  TIPA's `a with acute stacked on top of macron': & \textipa{\'=a}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

compiles in XeLaTeX as:

[image: 'native' Latin Modern Roman `a with acute stacked on top of macron' vs TIPA's version of same]

This a decent solution in many ways, but one issue is that the PDF-internal representation of the TIPA version is non-ideal. The (ugly) 'native' version copies-and-pastes out of the PDF document properly as `ā́`, but the TIPA version as `́ā`.

Is there any way to associate a 'Unicode' representation on top of the TIPA version (e.g. like an OCR layer of a scanned PDF)?

**Edit 1** (responding to @Davislor):

I am using `fontspec`, but wanted to use Latin Modern Unicode and still be able to use certain special characters I need in my document.

## Try using `ucharclasses`

This partially works, but creates other issues. For comparison, here are 'straight' Latin Modern and CMU samples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Contextuals=Alternate}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cmuserif}{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\cmusans}{CMU Sans Serif}
\newfontfamily{\cmutypewriter}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Latin Modern Roman}:\\  ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\
{\sffamily\noindent \textbf{Latin Modern Sans}:\\ ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\}
\texttt{\textbf{Latin Modern Typewriter}:\\
 ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}}\\

{\cmuserif\noindent\textbf{CMU Serif}:\\  ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\
{\cmusans\noindent \textbf{CMU Sans Serif}:\\ ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\}
{\cmutypewriter\noindent{\textbf{CMU Typewriter}:\\
ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}}\\}
\end{document}
```

[image: various diacritics and symbols in Latin Modern and CMU]

Latin Modern has significant issues for `ā́, ȭ, ī̀, ī́, R̥, r̥` (omitting the diacritic mark or mangling two diacritics together to indistinguishability) and poor typesetting for `ṁ` (where the overdot is misaligned). CMU generally gets these right (or at least results in readability), excepting the typewriter face. (Latin Modern has generally better-looking setting of accents and diaeresis/umlaut: éè üë ; and noticeably different type-setting of the Eszett ß.)

With `ucharclasses` we can fix some but not all of the Latin Modern issues, at the cost of losing access to sans serif and typewriter faces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Contextuals=Alternate}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Latin Modern Roman}[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]
\newfontfamily{\lmroman}{Latin Modern Roman}[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]
\newfontfamily{\lmsans}{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily{\cmuserif}{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\cmusans}{CMU Sans Serif}

\usepackage[Latin,LatinExtendedA]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedA}{\cmuserif}{} % fixes macron+acute, e.g. ā́
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedB}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedC}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedD}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedE}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{LatinExtendedAdditional}{\cmuserif}{} % fixes overdot, e.g. ṁ
%\setTransitionTo{LatinSupplement}{\cmuserif}{} % essets, ß etc.
\setTransitionTo{CombiningDiacriticalMarks}{\cmuserif}{} % should contain ring below (U+0325), but doesn't fix R̥ r̥ (!)
\setTransitionTo{CombiningDiacriticalMarksExtended}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{CombiningDiacriticalMarksForSymbols}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{CombiningDiacriticalMarksSupplement}{\cmuserif}{}
\setTransitionTo{CombiningHalfMarks}{\cmuserif}{}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Latin Modern Roman with CMU Serif `fixes' with \texttt{ucharclasses}}:\\  ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\
{\sffamily\noindent \textbf{Latin Modern Sans with CMU Serif `fixes' with \texttt{ucharclasses}}:\\ ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}\\}
\texttt{\textbf{Latin Modern Typewriter with CMU Serif `fixes' with \texttt{ucharclasses}}:\\
 ā́ ȭ R̥r̥ éè ā üë ì í ī ī̀ ī́ è ṁṭ ß \textit{ß R̥r̥ ā́ ȭ}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern with some charclasses replaced by CMU characters]

`ā́, ī̀, ī́, ṁ` are fixed, but `ȭ, R̥, r̥` remain garbled or missing diacritics. And the ability to use sans and typewriter faces disappears.

## Try using `catcode`

In the spirit of using `newunicodechar`, I tried the following:

```
\def\awithmacronacute{\textipa{\'=a}}
% or \def\awithmacronacute{\cmuserif{ā́}}
\catcode`\ā́=\active
\defā́{\awithmacronacute}
```

Unfortunately, `\catcode` doesn't work with characters which are combinations of combining unicode characters:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \ā́ 
l.17 \catcode`\ā́
                 =\active
?
```

## Try with `\ifpdfstringunicode`

I tried the following:

```
\def\awithacuteandmacron{%
  \texorpdfstring{\textipa{\'=a}}%
  {\ifpdfstringunicode{ā́}}}
```

While then calling `\awithacuteandmacron` typesets a ā́, it remains `' ā` when I try to copy it out of the PDF.

I think just using CMU fonts in place of Latin Modern is ultimately the best of a number of imperfect solutions, since CMU seems to have better glyph coverage and handles combining unicode much better than Latin Modern.

Comment: My advice is: if possible, switch to `fontspec`.  If you want to use a main font that doesn’t support IPA symbols, you can change the default font for that symbol with `ucharclasses` or `newunicodechar`.

Comment: Would `\ifpdfstringunicode` from `hyperref` work for you?

Comment: @Davislor: See edited question above.

Comment: Have you tried [`accsupp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf) ?

Comment: [`tipauni`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni)