# Are there any technique to make tabular contents non-renderable text?

Tags: tables, pdftex, article, rendering, ocr

I wonder whether any technique exists in LaTeX to make some parts non-renderable, for example, the contents in tabular data? Of course, if someone wants to recognize the texts (say from a table) using various OCR software programs, I do not want to readily recognize the text. Thank you.

Comment: I guess that by non-renderable you mean it can't be copied as text rom the resulting output (e.g. PDF) file.
You could run the special part seperately through LaTeX and convert it to a bit-map image, e.g. a PNG file, and include that in your final document.

Comment: What is the use case exactly, why do you want the text to be uncopyable/unrecognizable?

Comment: How "unrecognizable" do you want it?  Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/censor?

Comment: Thank you @StevenB.Segletes, for your comment. But I want the text to be visible but 'not-copyable.'

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn, I want some tabular data as 'not-copyable' in a document, whereas all texts except the table are copyable.

Comment: Thank you, @PietervanOostrum, I desire something directly from .tex to .pdf file.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf

Comment: @relinquere I understand what you want to do, but I asked for the reason why you want to do that. Knowing the reason can help us to give you advice if and how you can meet your (end) goal.