# What is the problem with characters < and > in PDF display?

Tags: fonts, symbols, pdf, characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include < and > symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10300/include-and-symbol)

Why when I create pdf in texlive with `pdflatex`, the characters `<` and `>` are displayed as inverted `!` and `?`, respectively. However, when I copy/past them, they are OK. What is the problem with PDF display. It's like the system does not have appropriate font, but aren't they common characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [Include `<` and `>` symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10300/2417).

Comment: @IanThompson You are right, but it is very difficult to search for characters like < and >; I tried but search engines including that of tex.stackexchange.com ignore them!

Comment: So they can be pasted correctly but are displayed wrong? This would be the opposite of [Angle symbols which can be copy and pasted from PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18146/angle-symbols-which-can-be-copy-and-pasted-from-pdf) then. This seems to be a font/language issue. Try to use a modern font and encoding. See [the comment below this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10303/2975)). Please post a minimal example which shows the behavior. Also please tell us the used version of TeXLive etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer as answered `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` solved the problem. I use TexLive 2011 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @Ali: Good to hear. Note that question is indeed a duplicate of the above linked question. In order to avoid unneeded redundancy I will close your question now. Feel free to accept an answer anyway, which is actually independent from closing.

Comment: @MartinScharrer your action was right; but please note that it was really hard to find the previous questions by search. I tried to accept the leading answer, but it has been deleted. Thus, I will delete the question too; but I think I can do this after two days.

Comment: @Ali: No problem. It is sometimes very difficult to find matching questions. Therefore having duplicate question around, which got linked to the first one, is actually beneficial because its increases the chance for future searches by other people. No reason to delete this question!

Answer (score 1):

The characters are math characters.  To get them to appear in text mode as inequalities you need to use `\(<\)` and `\(>\)`.

Comment: This did not solved the problem!

Comment: Ah, the reason for MWE.  As this is common question from my freshman LaTeX students when they are first doing math homework.  Using  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 with an appropriate font is where I eventually take the students.